# Laravel Display data from a different table

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to display all the records from my orderItems table but it is displaying data from my products table. How would I switch this round? Have I done my relationships backwards?

**desired results**
Display all order items from OrderItems table

**Product Model **

```
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\OrderItem;

class Product extends Model
{

    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'item_name', 'size', 'toppings','price',
    ];

    public function orderItem() {
        return $this->belongsTo(OrderItem::class,);

    }



}
```

**OrderItem Model **

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\Product;

class OrderItem extends Model
{

    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = ['product_id'];


    public function products_rel(){
      return $this-> hasMany(Product::class );

    }
    public function Order(){
    return $this->hasMany(Order::Class);
}
}
```

**orderItem Table**

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('order_items', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('product_id');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Products Table**

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreignId('order_item_id');

        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('size');
        $table->float('price');
        $table->foreignId('topping_id')->nullable();



    });
}
```

**orderItem Controller**

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\Order;
use App\Models\OrderItem;
use App\Models\Product;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class OrderItemsController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {


   $orderItems = OrderItem::all();
    return view('basket', ['orderItems'=> $orderItems]);
    }

    public function  create()
    {
        return view('welcome');
    }

    public function store ()
    {
    request()->validate([
        'product_id'=> 'required',

    ]);




        OrderItem::create([

            'product_id' =>request('product_id'),
        ]);

    }

}
```

**output html**

```
<table id="checkout">
    <tr>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Size</th>

    <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach($orderItems as $orderItem)
        @foreach($orderItem->products_rel as $related_product)
            <tr>
            <td>{{$related_product->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$related_product->size}}</td>

            <td>{{$related_product->price}}</td>
        </tr>


        @endforeach
    @endforeach

</table>
```

Comment: It seems more likely that an order item would have one associated product (`belongsTo`), and a product would be associated with many order items (`hasMany`).

Answer (score 2):

> desired results Display all order items from OrderItems table

This order_items table contains products, so it is normal to show products there !!!

I think your problem is that you are getting all the items in your order_item table with this `$orderItems = OrderItem::all();`
while you want the orders, so you should query on orders table.

```
    $orders = Order::all();
```

also you are showing the products your self in `foreach($orderItem->products_rel as $related_product)`

```
@foreach($orderItems as $orderItem)
        @foreach($orderItem->products_rel as $related_product)
            <tr>
            <td>{{$related_product->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$related_product->size}}</td>

            <td>{{$related_product->price}}</td>
        </tr>


        @endforeach
    @endforeach
```

so if you dont want the products delete the second **foreach**

Comment: The issue is its not displaying all the products